# python: error proof loop

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Say you have a situation where you want to run a function, and then ask the user if they would like to re-run the function. If the user chooses to re-run the function, it will re-run, and then the user will be asked again if they'd like to re-run the function. This process continues infinitely as long as the user says yes, and will be terminated if the user says no. For example:

```
def random_function():
    print('the function ran.')

random_function()

random_function()
re_run = input('Re-run random_function? y/n: ')

while ans != 'n' and ans == 'y':
    random_function()
    re_run = input('Re-run random_function? y/n: ')

print('The program will now close.')
```

Here, the user should only be inputting 'y' or 'n'. However, in the case the user inputs something other than 'y' or 'n', I'd like to return a message saying that only 'y' or 'n' are acceptable inputs, and then prompts them to re-enter their response. I know I should be using exceptions, but I having trouble figuring out how to use them. Can anyone shed some insight?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use exceptions, see code below.

```
def random_function():
    print 'the function ran.'


    flag=1
    while True:

        if flag:
            random_function()
        re_run = raw_input('Re-run random_function? y/n: ')
        if re_run != 'y' and re_run != 'n':
             print 'Pease use only y or n input'
             flag = 0
        elif re_run == 'n':
             break
        elif re_run == 'y' :
             flag = 1
```